# How can I display a mouse's walking process on linux terminal using c?

Tags: c, linux, maze

Now, I can get a direction txt file from my code:

```
down
down
right
right
up
.
.
.
```

I want to ask how can I display the walking process on linux terminal.
For instance, I want to use a dot representing a mouse which can execute the direction above.

Comment: [`man 3 ncurses`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man3/ncurses.3ncurses.html)

Comment: The only portable way to output to X & Y locations of a text console is with a curses library such as `ncurses`. It's not worth your time to try and do it with ANSI escape sequences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nCurses is the best solution. You can het help with the built-in manual:

```
man -s 3 ncurses
```

A simpler way to do so is to use [ANSI CSI escape sequences](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences):

```
printf("\x1B[A"); // Up
printf("\x1B[B"); // Down
printf("\x1B[C"); // Left
printf("\x1B[D"); // Right
```

To move up and print a dot:

```
printf("\x1B[A.");
```